# sddm xsetup location

Tags: 16.04, vino, kdm, sddm

I've been using `vino` (remote desktop access application) in 12.04 without any problem. I put an exec line in file `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsetup` in order to start vino server when the kdm starts (like `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server &`).

Now I've installed 16.04 and saw that kdm is replaced by sddm. There is no such an Xsetup file for sddm. How can I start vino when sddm starts?

Comment: Generally, the start up applications go with the desktop environment, not with the desktop manager.  What is your desktop environment?

Comment: I'm using KDE...

Comment: My aim is to start vino server when the login sceen appears, not after a user starts a session. I hope it is possible.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll look around a bit.

Answer (score 1):

create a sddm.config if it does not exist:

```
sddm --example-config > /etc/sddm.conf
```

In the XDisplay Section you will see the Xsetup script which is executed as user root:

```
[XDisplay]
# Xsetup script path
# A script to execute when starting the display server
DisplayCommand=/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup
```

Replace `DisplayCommand` with your own script and add `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` there.